# Launch a Dash app in a Google Colab Notebook

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

How to launch a Dash app (http://dash.plot.ly) from Google Colab (https://colab.research.google.com)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To my knowledge there is currently no straightforward way to do this.

Find below a workaround that is similar to setting up Tensorboard (https://www.dlology.com/blog/quick-guide-to-run-tensorboard-in-google-colab/).

Start with a code cell that sets up all things required for this workaround:

```
# How to run a Dash app in Google Colab

## Requirements

### Install ngrok
!wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
!unzip ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

### Run ngrok to tunnel Dash app port 8050 to the outside world. 
### This command runs in the background.
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok http 8050 &')

### Get the public URL where you can access the Dash app. Copy this URL.
! curl -s http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | python3 -c \
    "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])"

### Install Dash
!pip install dash==0.31.1  # The core dash backend
!pip install dash-html-components==0.13.2  # HTML components
!pip install dash-core-components==0.39.0  # Supercharged components
!pip install dash-table==3.1.7  # Interactive DataTable component (new!)
```

Add another code cell with your Dash app:

```
## Dash app (https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started)

### Save file with Dash app on the Google Colab machine
%%writefile my_app1.py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In a last code cell you can then start your Dash app (this cell will be busy until you stop the exection and thus, stop your Dash app).

```
### Run Dash app
!python my_app1.py
```

To access the Dash app copy & paste the **ngrok.io-URL** above to a new brower tab (NOT 127.0.0.1:8050) and wait a few seconds.

Comment: I am getting this error : This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment

Comment: It's just a warning. Everything works. However, as the warning says this is rather something you should not consider for a "production environment". See: https://dev.to/flippedcoding/difference-between-development-stage-and-production-d0p

Comment: It works for this example where you just build a small dictionary on the spot and use it as sample data. How would you go about passing a pandas dataframe to my_app1.py?

Comment: you run your dash application as regular application in jupyter notebook and see result by refreshing the tunnel link. Kindly check example link below, which I had created: https://www.kaggle.com/piyushrumao/interactive-dash-visualizations-in-notebook

Answer (score 13):

JupyterDash (the official library for running Dash in notebooks) now has support for running apps on Colab.

You can paste this code inside a colab notebook, and your app will show up inline:

```
!pip install jupyter-dash

import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()
# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("JupyterDash Demo"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.Label([
        "colorscale",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='colorscale-dropdown', clearable=False,
            value='plasma', options=[
                {'label': c, 'value': c}
                for c in px.colors.named_colorscales()
            ])
    ]),
])
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("colorscale-dropdown", "value")]
)
def update_figure(colorscale):
    return px.scatter(
        df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="size",
        color_continuous_scale=colorscale,
        render_mode="webgl", title="Tips"
    )
# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

[Here's a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtR2H.gif) of what the output looks like. You can also check out [this Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/xhlulu/73ffc0b920d72142ac1db5f1026616b0/jupyterdash-demo.ipynb).

Here's some more useful links:

- [v0.3.0 Release note](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash/releases/tag/v0.3.0)
- [JupyterDash Announcement](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e)
- [Official Repository](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash)
- [Demo apps using Hugging Face's transformers in Colab](https://community.plotly.com/t/42762/)

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I run it and get a Google 403 error. Any idea what that means? Also, you might want to update your imports to this:

`from dash import dcc
from dash import html` as the imports you have for dcc and html are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you. Guys, if xhlulu's suggestion doesn't run as expected you can edit the last row like this:

```
app.run_server(mode='inline',host="0.0.0.0",port=1005)
```

Comment: For reference, to shutdown the dash app: `app._terminate_server_for_port(host="127.0.0.1", port="1005")`

Answer (score 3):

I created a [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/FxEY1NOyhYQ) a while back showing how to share your Dash app within Google Colab. It's in the first 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install jupyter-dash==0.3.0
!pip install dash==2.0.0
```

It seems not every version of library works.
This version of library works for me in colab with jupyter-dash.