# Is there a way to turn Google Colab code into web services or rest APIs

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory

I have a Machine learning module which uses Google Colab's free GPU for NLP tasks, and I want to make a web app out of it. I've been thinking of using React js for frontend and spring boot for the back end and was wondering whether there is a way to connect the code at Google Colab with the backend.
Want to know other alternative suggestions to building a web app incorporating the ML module in Colab as well. Any sort of help is appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. But there's no good examples of it.

There's an example of serving local resources, using http-server. Flask examples used to work too. But not much else.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you suggest an example if possible, because I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: To start, see some links from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59741453/6729010)

Comment: Is there a more modern answer available?