# Which method for running Flask inside Google Colab is better?

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory

I have a GC notebook that I want to share with non tech-savvy end users, so I looked up how to run Flask and expose to the internet in order to access it, and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741453/is-there-a-general-way-to-run-web-applications-on-google-colab) with two different methods.?

I've tried out both of them, but I don't like idea of including my own authorization token inside a public notebook in order to use `ngrok`, and I'm worried about stuff like security when simply launching a server on a port. Can someone shine a light on the topic?